# Firebase Deployment Directory Structure

Tags: deployment, firebase, firebase-hosting

I'm receiving a 'not found' error on my successful sign-in url. Auth works great and I pass the target where I'd like to navigate using the sample FirebaseUI App:

'signInSuccessUrl': 'https://fezziwig.firebaseio.com/games/game1/index.html'

I've got a folder structure like this:
Root/public/games/game1/index.html

All my files are being deployed but I'm curious about the folder structure. Once it's sent up to Firebase is there any way to see the hosted contents in their control panel?

I tried keeping the firebase.json file in my root folder very simple:

{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}

I have created the games folders after running Firebase init. Is that part of the problem?

Anyway, long story short, I can login but get 'not found' when I try to navigate to a landing page.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I was trying to navigate to a path within the database and not an actual page.